# Can Pyscript dynamically update the innerHTML attribute within a py-script tag?

Tags: python, dom, innerhtml, pyscript

I've only just started playing with Pyscript, and I'm trying to use it to dynamically update some HTML markup on my page at run-time.  (I rarely program in Javascript, so there are plenty of gaps in my knowledge when it comes to programming the DOM, etc., etc).

If I start with this markup:

```
<div id="charts">This is a <b>Test</b>.</div>
<py-repl>
</py-repl>
```

I can type these next three lines of code into the py-repl prompt, using the innerHTML attribute to adjust the markup within the div tag, updating the page on-the-fly, like so:

```
from js import document
c = document.getElementById('charts')
c.innerHTML = "This is <i>another</i> test."
```

Sure enough, the new innerHTML markup replaces the older markup, the page updates, and all is well in the world (with the word "another" appearing italicised). This is exactly what I was expecting to happen.

However, when I use the *same code* within a py-script tag, like so:

```
<div id="charts">This is a <b>Test</b>.</div>
<py-script>
    from js import document
    c = document.getElementById('charts')
    c.innerHTML = "This is <i>another</i> test."
</py-script>
```

The markup is replaced with the string "This is another test.". The HTML markup is stripped away, as if I'd used innerTEXT instead of innerHTML. The page does update but, with the italics tag missing, I'm not seeing rendered markup, only the textual content.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help/pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyScript removes HTML markup from strings. To embed HTML, one option is to build the DOM elements like this:

```
<py-script>
from js import document

c = document.getElementById('charts')
c.innerHTML = ""

e = document.createTextNode("This is ")
c.appendChild(e)

e = document.createElement("i")
e.innerHTML = "another"
c.appendChild(e)

e = document.createTextNode(" test.")
c.appendChild(e)

</py-script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this, John - it worked, although I get a weird "[object Text]" message after my updated test string appears (on DuckDuckGo, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome - all on Mac). Any thoughts on what that might be?  Thanks, again.

Comment: @PaulBarry - PyScript is displaying the result of the last statement operation. For example, if you add the line `"hello"` at the end, you will find `hello` printed. This is a side effect of supporting libraries such as `matplotlib`. A workaround is to add Python code that does not return a displayable result such as `x = 1`. You could also define a hidden DOM div element and declare `<py-script output="id_of_hidden_div">`. The default output (stdout, stderr) will go to that div. Note: I have not tested this with `py-repl` which needs default output I think.

Comment: Thanks, again, my suspicions are confirmed.  My work-around was to add an empty string (`""`) as the last line of code before the closing `</py-script>` tag.  Like your  `x = 1` suggestion, it's a do-nothing statement which produces no visible output on screen.   Thanks for the `output` attribute heads-up.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to update the innerHTML of an element when using PyScript is to use the Element API and element.innerHTML. [Here's the documentation for Element](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/API/element.html).

```
from pyscript import Element
chart_element = Element("charts")
chart_element.element.innerHTML = "This is <i>another</i> test."
```

There's also the write method like this:

```
chart_element.write("text to write to the element")
```

but as far as I can tell this doesn't render HTML.

There's more useful information on how to write to HTML elements via PyScript [here](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/writing-to-page.html#writing-content-to-an-element).